# Solving System of Nonlinear Equations

Tags: equation-solving

My question is fully contained in the image below - for some reason StackExchange wasn't letting me post it due to some unknown formatting issue so I simply took a picture and attached it below.

[image: question]

After thinking about this a little more, I realized that I probably should be using Solve instead of NSolve. When I make this change, I get some crazy expressions for my variables and am not quite sure what to make of this. Specifically, because the output only gives me expressions for A0 and A4. Does this mean that A1,A2, and A3 are just 0? Or is it an indication that Mathematica is not recognizing them as variables?

```
clear["Global'*"];
e1 = A1 == a (1 + A0);
e2 = A1 + 2 A2 + 3 A3 + 4 A4 == 0;
e3 = A1 - 3 A0^2 A1 + 6 b*A3 == 0;
e4 = A1 + 2 A2 + 3 A3 + 4 A4 - 
   3*(A0 + A1 + A2 + A3 + A4)^2*(A1 + 2 A2 + 3 A3 + 4 A4) + 6*b*A3 
   + 24*b*A4 == 0;
e5 = A0 + A1/2 + A2/3 + A3/4 + A4/5 == c;
Solve[{e1, e2, e3, e4, e5}, {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4}, Reals]
```

Comment: It is now shown below with some added comments - sorry for the delay I was having some issues with the MathJax formatting. Notice I also made the change that $\lambda\rightarrow a, \gamma \rightarrow b, uB \rightarrow c$ because I had initially given them values and it was messing with my code.

Comment: Basically, I am hoping to be able to solve for $A_i$ in terms of those parameters

Comment: `Simplify[Reduce[{e1, e2, e3, e4, e5}, {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4}]]` seems to show there are a number of different possible cases, depending on the parameters and on the values of some of the variables. Carefully look through that, divide that up between each `||` and watch the `()`s and see if that shows you what you need to know.

Comment: @Bill when looking through this does "&&" mean "and"? Also, does "||" mean "or"?

Comment: Yes. You can even look at the help page and type `||` or `&&` in the Search box and tap <enter> and it will show you the name of the function when someone uses punctuation instead of the actual function name.

Comment: You might even try `LogicalExpand` on the output of that. That should turn all the nested mixture of `&&` and `||` into `first case || second case || third case || fourth case` and the `Root` that appears in all this mean that the stuff inside that `Root` is a polynomial that can't know exactly what the actual root is going to be without using decimal approximations or knowing the values of some more of the variables, look up `Root` in the help system for more info on that.

Comment: Have you tried simply scrolling to the right?  When I run your code on Mathematica 12.3.1 (Mac OS), I get four different solutions in terms of roots of algebraic equations, all of which include expressions for all five variables.  However, for some reason they're arranged in a table that goes off the right-hand side of the window.

Comment: First let vals=Solve[{e1,e2,...}]. Now just look at vals[[1]]. Very complicated but gives expressions for all A0,A1,A2,A3,A4. One is A0->-1/a(. . .) if condition. Click on condition to uniconize it. One condition reads If[a>0 && b<Root[{,a,c}] && -1<c<-1/Sqrt[3]. That's a precise solution for A0: So for example, let a=1, c=-3/4 and b<Root[{a,c}] which you can determine numerically. Now do the others. Then back-substitute to check it.  (Updated: corrected typos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

e1 = A1 == a (1 + A0);
e2 = A1 + 2 A2 + 3 A3 + 4 A4 == 0;
e3 = A1 - 3 A0^2 A1 + 6 b*A3 == 0;
e4 = A1 + 2 A2 + 3 A3 + 4 A4 - 
    3*(A0 + A1 + A2 + A3 + A4)^2*(A1 + 2 A2 + 3 A3 + 4 A4) + 6*b*A3 + 
    24*b*A4 == 0;
e5 = A0 + A1/2 + A2/3 + A3/4 + A4/5 == c;

sol = Solve[{e1, e2, e3, e4, e5}, {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4}, Reals] // 
  Simplify;

Dimensions@sol

(* {3, 5} *)
```

There are three solutions each with five parts, i.e., for `{A0, A1, A2, A3, A4}`. The results are in terms of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions. Looking at one example,

```
A01 = A0 /. sol[[1]]
```

[image]

Low order `Root` expressions can be converted to radical expressions using [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html). However, the expressions get much longer.

```
A01 // ToRadicals
```

[image]

With numeric values for `{a, b, c}`

```
sol /. {a -> 1., b -> 2., c -> 3.}

(* {{A0 -> -7.642, A1 -> -6.642, A2 -> 99.741, A3 -> -96.42, 
     A4 -> 24.105}, 
    {A0 -> 2.5437, A1 -> 3.5437, A2 -> -7.20882, A3 -> 5.43697, 
     A4 -> -1.35924}, 
    {A0 -> 4.0983, A1 -> 5.0983, A2 -> -23.5322, A3 -> 20.983, 
     A4 -> -5.24576}} *)
```